# Referencing a date from a cell in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am trying to track stock prices with Googlefinance function in Sheets. I can pull the price for a date with =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE((B2),"price",date(2019,12,13)),2,2) which is fine but I want to input the date with Column A which has date data. So, (A1) instead of (2019,12,13)but for some reason I get errors.

This seems simple but I cannot get it to pull the date from my column. Ive tried removing DATE and just using the cell but this also doesnt work.

Answer (score 4):

the formula that worked for me is

```
=index(GOOGLEFINANCE("YOUR_STOCK", "price",A1),2,2)
```

If, like you said, you already tried that and it did not work, you should link us a test sheet with your formula.

Answer (score 1):

make sure A1 is really a date. you can check this with

```
=ISDATE(A1)
```

the output should be `TRUE`. your formula is correct:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2; "price"; A1); 2; 2)
```